# How to create a user with more privileges than the currently logged in user in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm logged into a MariaDB instance as a user `admin`. The `admin` user has got the `GRANT` and `CREATE` privileges because it is supposed to add new users to the instance, with non-global privileges for particular databases. The `admin` user misses `DROP` and `DELETE` privileges *on purpose* because I don't want him to be able to delete data by accident. On the other hand, I want users *created by the `admin` user* to have `DROP` and `DELETE` privileges on particular tables.

By default, MariaDB doesn't allow me to create users that have a privilege that `admin` hasn't at all. I see the security consideration here, since users could easily exploit that right and create users with more "power". But is there any possibility to achieve my desired behaviour in MariaDB/MySQL?

Comment: See [MySQL: Grant Read-Only DB Access for one DB and Create/Drop Access for other DBs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/188568): you let "root" create a stored procedure with "security definer", which means that the procedure gets the permissions of the user that *created* the procedure - root - , and do everything you need to do inside that procedure (or several) with root privileges. The "admin"-user then only needs the rights to execute that procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on your linux console:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then your root password.

First we create the database ( yes database first)

```
CREATE DATABASE newdatabase;
```

Then we create the newuser with GRANT only for THIS newdatabase:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdatabase.* TO newuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'any_password';

flush privileges;

exit
```